# Как раскрыть календарь при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть `input` с типом `date`. По умолчанию, календарь раскрывается при клике на кнопку. Можно ли его раскрыть, при клике на весь `input`?
Вот код:

```
<input name="passport_date" class="input" required="required" type="date" value="">
```

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, с календарем, сейчас не понятно как календарь раскрывается.

Comment: это html5. Календарь раскрывается при клике на иконку. https://jsfiddle.net/a857157u/

Comment: используй jquery ui там есть datapicker calendar и кастомизируй как надо

Comment: Раньше его и использовали, а сейчас переходим на html5

Comment: @Misha Spring в мозилле(у меня 47 версия) не работает `type="date"` нормально как в хроме, лучше останьтесь на `jquery ui`, по крайней мере с датами